# How can you make the form maximize to any computer screen in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, screen, maximize

So I am making a game on Visual Studio C# and I want the form to 
be automatically maximized to any user's computer screen when compiled?
How can I do that?

Comment: I'm sure you mean when run, not compiled.

Comment: the answer depends on what platform you are coding for. WPF? Silverlight? WinForms? etc.

Answer (score 39):

You can do it using one of the following --

1. Set the form WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
2. Get the screen resolution using following code and set the size of your forms accordingly

   ```
   int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height; 
   int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
   ```

Comment: WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; // not WindowState=Maximized;

as for PrimaryScreen work alwyas only if one display or all other display do not have smaller size

Comment: You don't need to set Width and Height if state is Maximized. That does it alone

Answer (score 24):

Set the [WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx) property of your form to `Maximized`.

That will cause your form to be maximumized when it's opened.

Comment: In addition, the [FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx) can be set to `FormBorderStyle.None` to remove the border as well, for a more *true maximized feeling, no borders added*.

Answer (score 16):

You can use  `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`

Answer (score 7):

1. Go To Load Form As View Code and use This Code :

C#:

```
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

VB:

```
Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
```

Comment: This line is all you need

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something that will maximize your window on a first click and normalizes your window on a second click, this will help.

```
private void maximiseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //normalises window
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.CenterToScreen();
        }

        //maximises window
        else
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.CenterToScreen();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

correct in VS2010:

`this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;`

Answer (score 0):

On the Form Move Event add this:

```
    private void Frm_Move (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Top = 0; Left = 0;
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    }
```